# When is $F(x,t)=\int_0^tf(x,\eta)\,d\eta$ a continuous function of $x,t$?

Tags: calculus, integration, uniform-convergence

I have read some results about integrals of the form $$\int_D f(x,t)\,dt$$ for instance, the dominated convergence theorem and MCT. Also I see results for $F(x) = \int_0^\infty f(x,t)\,dt$  being continuous at $x_0$, provided $\int_0^t f(x,\eta)\,d\eta$ has a limit as $t \to \infty$ which is uniform in some open set around $x_0$. Also, under somewhat more stringent conditions, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^\infty  f(x, \eta) \,d\eta = \int_0^\infty  \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x, \eta) \,d\eta$. And of course if we fix $x_0$, of course $\int_0^t f(x_0,\eta)\,d\eta$ is continuous in $t$ by the continuity of the integral.

Suppose on the other hand we fix $t_0$. When is $F(x)=\int_0^{t_0} f(x,\eta)\,d\eta$ continuous at $x_0$? Since this should be easier than the improper integral mentioned above, it certainly seems strong enough that $f(x,\eta)$ converges uniformly as $t \to t_0$ in a neighborhood around $x_0$. But can we get by with less?

Is it then an easy extension to show when
$$F(x,t)=\int_0^tf(x,\eta)\,d\eta,$$

is a continuous multivariable function of $(x,t)$? What restrictions do we need on $f(x, \eta)$?

I apologize if these are easy consequences of the other theorems, and I'm just not seeing it. Also I apologize if these are canonical results that I don't know. A google search didn't help me to answer these questions.

Comment: In general I do not know, but if $f$ is continuous on a compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$ you can probably use uniform continuity of $f$ to prove continuity of $F$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is defined on $X\times I$, where $X$ is a metric space and $I$ is an interval of $\mathbb R$ containing $0$. Here is a reasonably general set of conditions ensuring that the function $F$ is well-defined and continuous:

(o) $f(x,t)$ is measurable with respect to $t$, for each fixed $x\in X$;

(i) $f(x,t)$ is continuous with respect to $x$, for each fixed $t\in I$;

(ii) for any compact set $K\subset X$ and any compact interval $J\subset I$, there is an integrable function $g:J\to \mathbb R_+$ such that $\vert f(x,\eta)\vert\leq  g(\eta)$ whenever $(x,\eta)\in K\times J$

Note that these conditions are satisfied if $f(x,t)$ is continuous wrt $x$ and $f$ is locally bounded on $X\times I$; in particular, this holds if $f$ is $jointly$ continuous on $X\times I$.

Conditions (o) and (ii) with $K=\{ x\}$ and $J=[0,t]$ implies that $F(x,t)$ is well-defined for any $(x,t)$.

To check continuity at some given point $(x,t)$, let us fix a sequence $(x_n,t_n)\subset X\times I$ converging to $(x,t)$. Then $K=\{ x\}\cup \{ x_n;\; n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a compact subset of $X$, and one can find a compact interval $J\subset I$ containing $\{ t\}\cup\{ t_n;\; n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{ 0\}$. Let $g:J\to\mathbb R_+$ be chosen according to (ii). Assuming for example $t_n\geq t$, one can write 
\begin{eqnarray*} 
\left\vert F(x_n,t_n)-F(x,t)\right\vert&=&\left\vert \int_0^{t_n} f(x_n,\eta)\, d\eta-\int_0^t f(x,\eta)\, d\eta\right\vert\\ 
&=&\left\vert \int_t^{t_n} f(x_n,\eta)\, d\eta+\int_0^t \left(f(x_n,\eta)-f(x,\eta) \right)\, d\eta\right\vert\\
&\leq& \int_t^{t_n} g(\eta)\, d\eta +\int_J \vert f(x_n,\eta)-f(x,\eta) \vert\, d\eta
\end{eqnarray*}

The second integral in the right-hand side goes to $0$ by (i) the dominated convergence theorem; and the first one as well by dominated convergence again, because it can be written as $\int_J \mathbb 1_{(t,t_n)}(\eta)g(\eta)\, d\eta$.
This shows that $F$ is continuous at $(x,t)$.